# C# value-type Tuple items not matching?

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain why `Item1 == Item2` of this `Tuple<object,object>` evaluates to false when both `Item1` and `Item2` are both the boolean value `false`?

[image]

Comment: I note that `if (x == y) return true; else return false;` could be written much more easily as `return x==y;`

Comment: See marked duplicate. The comparison you are making is of the _references_ of the boxed values, not the values themselves. Same issue the OP in the marked duplicate had. See his own resolution, i.e. use `Equals()`, and answers to his question, for alternatives that will do what you want.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you. I didn't really know what to search for, but I can see that the root cause is identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way `==` works since it does't traverses the hierarchy tree and simply uses the type of the value (because it is not a virtual overridable method but an operator instead), which is boxed so Object, that functions by reference check, so if they aren't the *exact same object* (not value) it will return false.

As you yourself said in your answer they got boxed to an object. Therefore to fix this, you can use `Equals` which fixes your problem as C# goes to the topmost child of the value (which in your case would be `Boolean.Equals` instead of `operator ==` from Object):

```
var allEqual = together.All(tuple => tuple.Item1.Equals(tuple.Item2));
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure it's because of [Boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx). The `Tuple`'s items are both `object`s, so the `==` operator is performing a reference comparison. Since `Item1` gets boxed into a different `object` than `Item2`, the `==` reference comparison returns false.

Comment: They got boxed *to* an object

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thank you for the clarification